# Troubles to Install REPL in Sublime 3 and 4

Tags: sublimetext, sublimerepl, sublimetext4

As you can see on the screen I am having trouble installing the REPL. I have checked lot of questions but I could not find the same situation.
My problem is at the first moment because I cannot even install it.
I´d tried to uninstall and install it again but is the same.
Maybe someone can help me, it is super basic but I don know what to change in the console.
[image]

When I check the console, I can see this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjLUq.png)

This is the Console code:

```
DPI mode: per-monitor v2
startup, version: 4113 windows x64 channel: stable
executable: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text/sublime_text.exe
application: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text
working dir: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text
packages path: /C/Users/Samsung/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages
state path: /C/Users/Samsung/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Local
zip path: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text/Packages
zip path: /C/Users/Samsung/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages
ignored_packages: ["Vintage"]
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - City Lights/assets/reverse.png
pre session restore time: 0.162259
startup time: 0.235259
first paint time: 0.237259
reloading plugin Default.arithmetic
reloading plugin Default.auto_indent_tag
reloading plugin Default.block
reloading plugin Default.colors
reloading plugin Default.comment
reloading plugin Default.convert_color_scheme
reloading plugin Default.convert_syntax
reloading plugin Default.copy_path
reloading plugin Default.echo
reloading plugin Default.exec
reloading plugin Default.fold
reloading plugin Default.font
reloading plugin Default.goto_line
reloading plugin Default.history_list
reloading plugin Default.html_print
reloading plugin Default.indentation
reloading plugin Default.install_package_control
reloading plugin Default.keymap
reloading plugin Default.kill_ring
reloading plugin Default.mark
reloading plugin Default.new_templates
reloading plugin Default.open_context_url
reloading plugin Default.open_in_browser
reloading plugin Default.pane
reloading plugin Default.paragraph
reloading plugin Default.paste_from_history
reloading python 3.3 plugin 0_package_control_loader.00-package_control
reloading plugin Default.profile
reloading plugin Default.quick_panel
reloading plugin Default.rename
reloading plugin Default.run_syntax_tests
reloading plugin Default.save_on_focus_lost
reloading plugin Default.scroll
reloading plugin Default.set_unsaved_view_name
reloading plugin Default.settings
reloading python 3.3 plugin Package Control.1_reloader
reloading plugin Default.show_scope_name
reloading plugin Default.side_bar
reloading python 3.3 plugin Package Control.2_bootstrap
reloading plugin Default.sort
reloading plugin Default.switch_file
reloading plugin Default.symbol
reloading plugin Default.transform
reloading plugin Default.transpose
reloading plugin Default.ui
reloading plugin CSS.css_completions
reloading plugin Diff.diff
reloading plugin HTML.encode_html_entities
reloading plugin HTML.html_completions
reloading plugin ShellScript.ShellScript
reloading python 3.3 plugin Package Control.Package Control
plugins loaded
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2021-10-22 17:50:33, next run at 2021-10-22 18:50:33 or after
ignored packages updated to: ["SublimeREPL", "Vintage"]
reloading settings Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings
reloading settings Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
Package Control: Attempting to use Urllib downloader due to WinINet error: Error downloading package. Host not found (errno 12007) during HTTP write phase of downloading https://codeload.github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/zip/2.1.2.
Package Control: Error downloading package. URL error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed downloading https://codeload.github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/zip/2.1.2.
error: Package Control
```

Comment: What does the console (**`View → Show Console`**) say? Please copy the *entire* error message, [edit] your post, and paste it into your question's body as formatted text.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your help. I add that info, but actually don't know what to do to solve it.

Comment: How are you connecting to the internet? Do you use a VPN or proxy? What country are you in? For some reason Package Control is unable to connect to Github.